# HTML, closing tags is ok?

Tags: html, tags

I´m researching about HTML5 and have maybe a stupid doubt:

**Can I close the tags? Will this affect the functionality?**

Examples:

HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
// Is the same <!DOCTYPE html /> ?

<html lang="en">
// Is the same <html lang="en" /> ?

<meta charset =" utf-8">
Is the same <meta charset =" utf-8" /> ?
```

I ask this because in ALL the books I read show tags without closing slash. I understand the "new manner", the lack of need, etc, etc, etc. **I just want to know if the use of closed tags could be a problem or goes against the standard.**

Comment: 1. No, never. 2. Is invalid. 3. Ordinarily yes.

Comment: @Alohci Invalid JUST for these ones or for ALL the tags?

Comment: `<html lang="en" />` is invalid. But, in contrast, for example, `<math>` is different from `<math />` but both may be used in a valid way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5 you can still close the tags as in XML. The change that was made in HTML5 was that it is now valid to *not* close single element tags such as `<input>`, `<meta>`, etc., but it's completely optional.

```
<!-- valid -->
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<!-- also valid -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I wanted to know. Because in ALL the books appear the unclosed tags. But if it´s still valid, I´m ok and happy with that :D Thanks again! Small doubt, great response.